# send FCM Push Notification after every 3 hours interval using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am trying to send a push notification to the users who were yesterday active on our platform to sending once in a day in the morning in an automated way is i am able to do. but sending after 4 hours i am unable to think how am i send them after 4 hours like i have sent a push notification in the morning around 6 and then around 10AM and then 2PM and then around 6PM but after 6 pm i don't want to send a push notification to the users.how can i solve this problem.

basically, for one time I will query the timestamp between yesterday start time and end time and then i will able to extract the yesterday active users and then i am able to get the devicetoken and then I am simply sending the push notification.but how to send on an interval please suggest any solution

```
    const start = momentTz()
        .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
        .subtract(1, "days")
        .startOf("day")
        .format();
    
      const end = momentTz()
        .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
        .subtract(1, "days")
        .endOf("day")
        .format();
      const profileSnapshot = await db
        .collection("Profiles")
        
         .where("lastQueryFrom", ">=", momentTz(start).valueOf())
         .where("lastQueryFrom", "<=", momentTz(end).valueOf())
        .get();
    
      const profile = [];
      profileSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        profile.push(doc.data().phoneNumber);
//here i will get the device token and i will run the fcm push notification logic
      });
      console.log(profile.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has [scheduled functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) which you can schedule an interval which can perform the check you mentioned and send out push notification. You can schedule it every 4 hours. You can of course exit the funcition early outside of the time range you mentioned.

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
  // get active users and send push notification
  return null;
});
```